# SQL Oracle Query - Left Outer Join on null Field

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join

I have this query

```
SELECT   *
    FROM (SELECT mi.visit_id, mi.event_id, mi.patient_id, mi.mrn, mi.reg_date,
                 mi.d_date, mi.bml_count, mi.TYPE, mblp.baby_patient_id,
                 mblp.baby_birthdate
            FROM ajmid.km0076_motherinfo_test mi LEFT JOIN alfayezb2.mbl_patients mblp
                 ON mblp.mother_patient_id = mi.patient_id
                 --works here 
               AND (   TO_CHAR (mblp.baby_birthdate, 'mm/dd/YYYY') =
                                           TO_CHAR (mi.reg_date, 'mm/dd/YYYY')
                    OR TO_CHAR (mblp.baby_birthdate, 'mm/dd/YYYY') =
                                       TO_CHAR (mi.reg_date - 1, 'mm/dd/YYYY')
                    OR TO_CHAR (mblp.baby_birthdate, 'mm/dd/YYYY') =
                                       TO_CHAR (mi.reg_date + 1, 'mm/dd/YYYY')
                   )
                 ) bml
         LEFT OUTER JOIN --doesn't work here
         (SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY vis.patient_id ORDER BY vis.admission_date_time)
                                                                          num,
                 vis.admission_date_time, vis.visit_id, vis.patient_id,
                 vis.facility_id
            FROM visit vis) v ON bml.baby_patient_id = v.patient_id
   WHERE v.num = 1
ORDER BY bml.reg_date
```

bml by itself returns 118 rows while the whole query returns 117, the reason is bml returns 1 row with baby_patient_id as null, so I used left outer join to show it, but it's still not showing !!

what can I do to show all rows of bml ?

I'm using Toad 9.6

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The probable cause is your filter / criteria (where clause) is eliminating a row with a null value for v.num. The WHERE filters the results after the join.

```
 WHERE v.num = 1   -- Are all v.num equal to 1 ?
```

The mere action of using a criteria against a field, by definition of what NULL means, eliminates that row from consideration because NULL cannot be evaluated. You can say "WHERE id != 1" and expect to get rows where id is null because null != 1 right? Wrong. id != NULL is not defined logically. It is why we say "IS or IS NOT NULL" when dealing with NULL.

Comment: v.num is a partitioning factor, I need to get the first visit from the visit table, the record I wanna show doesn't include any data in mbl_patients nor in visit, but I managed to show the data in bml query nonetheless it's not showing for the whole query although I used the same technique (LEFT JOIN) to show it in bml inner query

Comment: Then you may need to use NVL(v.num, 1) in the outer query, because your where clause as it stands is filtering (eliminating) rows with null num.

Comment: I've tried removing the condition (although I need it), but still the record doesn't show up !

Comment: I've tried changing it as well to    WHERE NVL (v.num, 1) but I got an error saying ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

Comment: it's working finally !
I added OR bml.baby_patient_id IS NULL to the last where clause, I don't know how this was helpful, I wish someone would explain for me !

Comment: Because, as I said above, the mere action of using a criteria against a field, by definition of what NULL means, eliminates that row from consideration. You can say "WHERE id != 1" and still not get back rows with NULL id because id != NULL is not defined logically. It is why we say "IS or IS NOT NULL" when dealing with NULL

Answer (score 0):

check the query:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY vis.patient_id ORDER BY vis.admission_date_time)
                                                                          num,
                 vis.admission_date_time, vis.visit_id, vis.patient_id,
                 vis.facility_id
            FROM visit vis
```

does it return 118 not null patient_id's?

if it returns 117, that might be the reason.(`LEFT OUTER JOIN` doesnot pick the records which are null on both tables)

Also, are you sure the null value of `baby_patient_id` in `bml` table is actually a `NULL` value and not a empty charater?(' ').

Comment: the partitioned table visit returns more than 118!! in the other hand I tried adding bml.baby_patient_id like ' ' but didn't work !

Answer (score 0):

it's working finally !
I added

```
      OR bml.baby_patient_id IS NULL
```

to the where clause, so the final script is

```
SELECT   *
FROM (SELECT mi.visit_id, mi.event_id, mi.patient_id, mi.mrn, mi.reg_date,
             mi.d_date, mi.bml_count, mi.TYPE, mblp.baby_patient_id,
             mblp.baby_birthdate
        FROM ajmid.km0076_motherinfo_test mi LEFT JOIN alfayezb2.mbl_patients mblp
             ON mblp.mother_patient_id = mi.patient_id
           AND (   TO_CHAR (mblp.baby_birthdate, 'mm/dd/YYYY') =
                                       TO_CHAR (mi.reg_date, 'mm/dd/YYYY')
                OR TO_CHAR (mblp.baby_birthdate, 'mm/dd/YYYY') =
                                   TO_CHAR (mi.reg_date - 1, 'mm/dd/YYYY')
                OR TO_CHAR (mblp.baby_birthdate, 'mm/dd/YYYY') =
                                   TO_CHAR (mi.reg_date + 1, 'mm/dd/YYYY')
               )
             ) bml
     LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY vis.patient_id ORDER BY vis.admission_date_time)
                                                                      num,
             vis.admission_date_time, vis.visit_id, vis.patient_id,
             vis.facility_id
        FROM visit vis) v ON bml.baby_patient_id = v.patient_id
    WHERE v.num = 1
      OR bml.baby_patient_id IS NULL
    ORDER BY bml.reg_date
```

I don't know how this was helpful, I wish someone would explain for me !
Thanks all